# Reversi Game Legal Move

Tags: python

I am having trouble with a function in my reversi logic code. The function is the isLegalMove I am asked to  "Return a Boolean indicating if the current player can place their chip in the square at position (row, col). Both row and col must be valid indices​."
So I came up with my code below, however a move I make in the game says Error: not a legal move.
Please help!

Code:

```
from ezarrays import Array2D

# Values representing the color of the chips on the board.
EMPTY = 0
BLACK = 1
WHITE = 2

class ReversiGameLogic :

 # Creates an instance of Reversi game logic with the board correctly
 # initialized and the current player set to black.
 def __init__(self) :
 # Use a 2-D array to represent the board.
  self._gameBoard = Array2D(8, 8)
  self._gameBoard.clear(EMPTY)

 # Set the initial configuration of the board.
  self._gameBoard[4,3] = BLACK
  self._gameBoard[3,4] = BLACK
  self._gameBoard[3,3] = WHITE
  self._gameBoard[4,4] = WHITE

 # Maintain the number of the current player.
  self._currentPlayer = BLACK

 # Keep track of the number of each players chips.
  self._numBlackChips = 2
  self._numWhiteChips = 2

 # A flag that is set when the game is over. That is, when there are
 # no empty squares on the board or neither player can make a move.
  self._gameOver = False

 # Returns a boolean indicating whether the game is over.
  def isOver(self) :
   isOver = 0
   for i in range(8) :
    for j in range(8) :
      if self._gameBoard[i, j] != 0 :
      isOver + 1
   if isOver == 64 :
     self._gameOver = True
     return True
   else:
     return False

 # Returns the player number of the current player.
 def whoseTurn(self) :
  if self._currentPlayer == 1:
   return 1
  else:
   self._curentPlayer == 2
  return 2


 # Returns the number of chips on the board for the given player.
 def numChips(self, player) :
  chipCounter = 0
  if player == 1 :
   for i in range(8) :
     for j in range(8) :
      if self._gameBoard[i, j] == BLACK :
        chipCounter = chipCounter + 1
  else : 
   for i in range(8) :
     for j in range(8) :
       if self._gameBoard[i, j] == WHITE :
        chipCounter = chipCounter + 1 
  return chipCounter

 # Returns the number of open squares on the board.
 def numOpenSquares(self) :
  numOpenSquares = 0
  for i in range(8) :
   for j in range(8) :
     if self._gameBoard[i, j] == EMPTY :
       numOpenSquares =  numOpenSquares + 1
  return numOpenSquares

 # Returns the player number of the winner or 0 if it's a draw.
  def getWinner( self ):
  player1 = 0
  player2 = 0
  if self._gameOver is True :
  for i in range(8) :
    for j in range(8) :
      if self._gameBoard[i, j] == BLACK :
        player1 = player1 + 1
      else :
        player2 = player2 + 1
  if player1 > player2 :
    return 1
  if player2 > player1 :
    return 2
  else:
    return 0

 #  
 def isLegalMove( self, row, col):
  if row < 8 and col < 8:
   if self._gameBoard[row,col] != EMPTY:
     return True
  else:
    return False



 # Returns the player number whose chip occupies the given square.
 def occupiedBy(self, row, col):
  if self._gameBoard[row, col] == BLACK :
    return 1
  if self._gameBoard[row, col] == WHITE :
    return 2
  else:
    return 0

 # Performs an actual move in the game. That is the current player places
 # one of his chips in the square at position (row, col).
 def makeMove( row, col ):
  if isALineOfAttack(row, col, 1, 1) is True :
   if self._currentPlayer == 1 :
     self._gameBoard[row, col] = BLACK
   else :
     self._gameBoard[row, col] = WHITE 










# Helper method that returns a Boolean indicating if there is a line of
# attack from cell (row, col) in the direction offset given by rowInc
# and colInc. The direction offsets should be, 0, 1, or -1.
def _isALineOfAttack(self, row, col, rowInc, colInc) :
 row += rowInc
 col += colInc
# The next cell in the line must contain the opponents chip.  
 if self.occupiedBy(row, col) == self._currentPlayer :
   return False

# Traverse along the line and determine if it's a line of attack.
 while row >= 0 and col >= 0 and row < 8 and col < 8 :
   if self.occupiedBy(row, col) == self._currentPlayer :
     return True
   elif self.occupiedBy(row, col) == EMPTY :
     return False
   else :
     row += rowInc
     col += colInc
     if row < 0 or row > 7 or col < 0 or col > 7 :
          return False      
 return False
```

Comment: Hey lindsey, please format your code correctly (indents and such). Right now it's really hard to read, plus I can't copy-paste it to test your code

Comment: Hate to say it, but it doesn't look fixed to me, still hard to read because of lack of indentation. Maybe this is just my browser, but you should double check

Comment: @en_Knight it is fixed

Comment: Is the whole code in the class?

Comment: @jakekimds it is the whole code just for the reversilogic there is another seperate py file for the game and the gui

Comment: My interpretation of your indenting: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/122705406/Stack%20Overflow%20Answers/Reversi.py

Comment: @jakekimds yes that it is how it is indented in wing ide but for some reason is not copying and pasting over correctly. I apologize

Comment: BTW, in Python, we don't useCamelCase. We_use_underscores.

Comment: @jakekimds yea my professor likes the camelcase

Comment: @lindsey Beware of tabs ... in code they cause far more problems than they are worth.  Try making sure you've converted all your tabs to spaces and it'll be more robust copying it *anywhere*.  Also, it's not actually fixed ... `def isOver` is defined inside of `__init__` right now.  Worst comes to worst, just fix it yourself by hand in the post.

Comment: Many of the else's in the functions can be removed

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of your indentation for `isLegalMove()`:

```
def isLegalMove( self, row, col ):
    if row < 8 and col < 8:
        if self._gameBoard[row,col] != EMPTY:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Noticeable problems:

1. If row and col are both less than 8, but `self._gameBoard[row,col] == EMPTY` in which case your function does not return anything.
2. You are returning `True` when `self._gameBoard[row,col] != EMPTY`, does that mean it is only legal to place chips on top of existing chips on the board?

The solution I recommend:

1. First perform input validation on `row` and `col`, to make sure they are within the bounds of your board. Return `False` immediately if they are not.
2. Next, return `True` if there is no chip on the board yet at `[row, col]`. `False` otherwise.

EDIT:

Assuming your board is fixed sized, 8x8.

```
def isLegalMove( self, row, col ):
    if row < 0 or row >= 8 or col < 0 or col >= 8:
        return False

    if self._gameBoard[row,col] == EMPTY:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: I wanted you to code it up... it's literally just translating my sentences into code. - but, I got nothing better to do right now, so sure

Comment: makes since the only issue I get now is that each move i make in the game is a black chip only, no white chip, and the game stays on black's turn...???